# Problemas com link e query

Tags: php

Olá, estou fazendo um site em que preciso de mudar a consulta quando eu clicar em um link.
Por exemplo, tenho um produto, anel, e quero dividir em anel de ouro e de prata.
No início da página fiz uma consulta:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' ORDER BY relevancia DESC";
```

aí no conteúdo da página eu criei os links:

```
<ul>
            <li ><a onclick="<?php $sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' ORDER BY relevancia DESC"; ?>">Todos</a></li>
            <li ><a onclick="<?php $sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' AND classificacao='ouro' ORDER BY relevancia DESC"; ?>">Ouro</a></li>
            <li ><a onclick="<?php $sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' AND classificacao='prata' ORDER BY relevancia DESC"; ?>">Prata</a></li>
        </ul>
```

e minhas imagens ficaram abaixo, assim:

```
$sql1=mysql_query($sql);
                while($dados=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                echo "<li><a href=".$dados['foto']." onclick='".mysql_query($res)."' style=' margin-left:0' data-lightbox='image-1' data-title=".$aux2.">
            <img  style=' width:200px; height:150px;  ' border='0' alt='image 02' src=".$dados['foto']." />
            <figcaption>".$dados['nome']." - ".$dados['codigo']."</figcaption></a></li>     ";}
```

Porém, ele executa, à princípio a ultima consulta, selecionando apenas os produtos de prata. E eu queria que à princípio exibisse todos, e quando eu clicasse no link ouro, por exemplo, ele atualizasse a página apenas com os aneis de ouro.

Comment: Porquê que não fazes isso com jquery seria mais fácil ?

Comment: Seu código não faz o mínimo sentido. O PHP é executado no servidor. Depois de executado, a página resultante é enviada para o usuário. Só então o JavaScript é executado. Você simplesmente está atribuindo uma string a $sql três vezes, e só usando a última. Além disso, seu "onclick" vai vazio para o cliente, pois o PHP não está "imprimindo" nada dentro dele. Seria legal se você se dedicasse a testes mais simples até entender o PHP, para depois pular para esta etapa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é assim que funciona. O [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) é um atributo do *HTML* que executa um código Javascript do lado do *cliente*. Quando você chama 3 vezes `$sql = ...`, na verdade está executando código PHP do lado do *servidor* e descartando o conteúdo que foi passado nas duas vezes anteriores.

Basicamente o está sendo executado é isso:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' ORDER BY relevancia DESC"; 
$sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' AND classificacao='ouro' ORDER BY relevancia DESC";
$sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' AND classificacao='prata' ORDER BY relevancia DESC";
```

Ou seja, `$sql` *sempre* vai conter o último valor passado.

Uma forma de obter o funcionamento desejado é passar um parâmetro para o PHP através da URL e então montar o SQL de acordo.

Você pode pegar parâmetros passados na URL através da global [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php).

Exemplo:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
   <li ><a href="seu_script.php?filtro=todos">Todos</a></li>
   <li ><a href="seu_script.php?filtro=ouro">Ouro</a></li>
   <li ><a href="seu_script.php?filtro=prata">Prata</a></li>
</ul>
```

**PHP:** (algo assim)

```
<?php
$extra = '';

if(!empty($_GET['filtro'])) {
  $filtro = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['filtro']);

  // caso exista um parâmetro "filtro" na URL, a query vai conter o conteúdo extra "AND classificacao='[VALOR-DO-FILTRO-PASSADO]'"
  // caso o filtro seja igual a "todos" (ou não seja passado), nada será adicionado ao SQL e a query vai retornar todos os itens normalmente    
  if($filtro != 'todos') {
      $extra =  " AND classificacao='{$filtro}'";
  }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE tipo='aneis' {$extra} ORDER BY relevancia DESC";

// aqui a query já está pronta!
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!