# Atualizar contador de fotos instantaneamente

Tags: php

Eu estou fazendo um site, em que exibo produtos que estão cadastrados em um banco de dados. Na tabela, tem um campo que chamo de relevancia e queria que quando alguém clicasse na imagem eu incrementasse esse campo.
Não tenho nem ideia de como fazer isso e queria algumas dicas. Tentei por no onclick da imagem uma função php que desse update nesse campo, mas sei que não funciona fazer assim pelo modo como onclick funciona.

Apesar de saber que não funcionaria, segue o código abaixo pra dar pra entender o que eu queria que acontecesse:

```
while($dados=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $aux=$dados['relevancia']+1;
                    $res= "UPDATE cwfolheados.produtos SET relevancia=".$aux." WHERE codigo=".$dados['codigo']."";
                echo "<li><a href='".$dados['foto']."' onclick='mysql_query($res)' style=' margin-left:0' data-lightbox='image-1' data-title=".$aux2.">
            <img  style=' width:200px; height:150px;  ' border='0' alt='image 02' src='".$dados['foto']."' />
            <figcaption>".$dados['nome']." - ".$dados['codigo']."</figcaption></a></li>     ";}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode montar uma estrutura de código utilizando o método jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

**HTML:**

```
<img id="img-id" class="img-class" src="img/imagem.jpg" alt="Minha imagem" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.img-class').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
    var id = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: id
    }).done(function(data) {
        if ( data == 'relevancia incrementada' ) {
            alert('Sucesso.');
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if ( !isset( $_POST["id"] || empty($_POST["id"]) ) ) {
        echo "id nao setado ou nulo";
        exit();
    }

    $id = $_POST["id"];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "root", "");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE tabela SET relevancia = relevancia + 1 WHERE codigo = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id );

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ( $result > 0 ) {
            return "relevancia incrementada";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return "erro: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

- <sub>Note que o `id` de cada imagem será recuperado previamente do banco de dados.</sub>
- <sub>Utilizei `PDO` no exemplo, mas também funciona com as funções `mysql_` embora seja altamente recomendado abandonar tais funções.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Como expliquei na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53065/20594), o atributo `onclick` não pode ser usado deste modo.

Tudo que você precisa é rodar o *update* cada vez que o script que mostra o produto for carregado. Desta forma a cada visualização o contador será incrementado em 1.

Ex.:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cwfolheados.produtos SET relevancia=relevancia+1 WHERE codigo=".$dados['codigo'].");
```

Usei como base sua *query* e modifiquei apenas a soma do valor da coluna (que pode ser feita diretamente no SQL). Assumi também que o código do produto está em `$dados['codigo']` como você informou.

Outra coisa, não existe necessidade de usar `while` quando você sabe que sua query irá retornar apenas um resultado (um só produto neste caso). Você pode usar apenas `$dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql);` que o efeito será o mesmo.